# Python + Django + Gunicorn on AWS: 2 workers, worker terminated due to signal 15 -> Failed to boot

Tags: django, gunicorn

I'm pretty new using django + gunicorn + aws. Im struggling to find the problem on "signal 15 from gunicorn". Below are the log file from gunicorn.

https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/2755